# java <identifier> expected error in main function

Tags: java

Could anyone help me check why "error: < identifier > expected" occurs? Thank you very much.

Basically, I write a java file called Entropy.java which contains several public static functions and the main function. When I called those public static functions in the main function, the compiler reported "error: < identifier > expected".

Here is my code for the main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str1= args[0];
    String str2= args[1];



    String prob1= Arrays.toString(Entropy.normalize.(Entropy.charCount(str1)));

    System.out.println("Character Probablities in "+args[0]+" : "+prob1);

}
```

The "< identifier > expected" error happens when I called Entropy.normalize and Entropy.charCount. They are the public static functions in the same class and same file, namely "Entropy.java". I am sure that those static functions are correct.

```
public static int[] charCount(String s)
public static double[] normalize(int[] c)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that perhaps the compiler cannot see your `Entropy` class.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you very much! Seems that I made a small error. Oops.

Comment: This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a **simple typographical error**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The

```
...normalize.(Entropy.charCount...
//          ^
```

part is wrong. You can't have a parentheses right after a member access operator. `.` is looking for method name on its right, but is finding a parenthesis instead. To call `normalize`, just get rid of the `.`.

Comment: I decided to post an answer even though this is basically a typo. It has a clear error message, and could be of help to someone in the future. Even if someone doesn't have this exact issue, someone weird after a member access operator will give the same error, and this may help.